# getimagesize () command problem! Loop promlem in command getimagesize ()

Tags: php, image, getimagesize

getimagesize () command in the For loop and the Foreach loop gives the same erroneous result. I just couldn't fix it. What is the reason for this, how can I fix it? 
I take the picture files from the same folder, but it always just gives the last one. When I apply the command one by one to the pictures, there is no problem, but when I loop, why am I having problems Also the pictures are a bit big. If this is the case, how can I make the loop synchronize with the command?

the command is as follows;

```
$file = file_get_contents("sss.txt");
$files = explode("\n", $file);

foreach( $files as $Xfile ) {

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('ebat_al/'.$Xfile);
echo "genislik = " . $width . "<br>";
echo "yükseklik = " . $height . "<br>";

}
```

/*

The results are always like;

genislik =

yükseklik =

genislik =

yükseklik =

genislik =

yükseklik =

genislik =

yükseklik =

genislik = 5000

yükseklik = 5000

I would be glad if you could help.

Comment: 5000x5000 px in the last data, txt size can not be! :( but still thank you. Here is the way of the picture: "  ('ebat_al/'.$Xfile)  "

Comment: Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also said I would upload it to the web server and try it and it worked fine. but why is my wamp not working? What could be the reason for this?